# Odd behaviour in android studio: git detects no changes

Tags: git, android-studio

Clicking VCS -> commit brings "No changes detected". But some files ARE changed. If I go to project's directory and type git diff, then I see changes pending.

The trouble is, changed files are not blue in studio. If I edit any file then it turns blue, but as soon as I hit ctrl+s the file turns black again! So it seems that the problem is somewhere in Android studio itself.

Now if I choose "Invalidate caches and restart", then changed files appear as blue and I can commit them. However if I try to change other files, they behave like described above -- no blue color on change. And these changed are NOT detected when VCS -> commit invoked, only changed files before invalidation.

So, basically I have to click invalidate caches before every commit (and no blue color on changed files is annoying too). Any ideas how to fix it?

Android studio 3.5, latest. Kubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, nothing speical.

Edit: Re-creating project from git repository from scratch, without .idea folder did not help. It seems to be an issue with android studio itself.

Edit2: Erasing ~/.AndroidStudio3.5 did not help. Problem persists. I have the same setup -- the same studio and same OS at home, no problems there.

Edit3: Deleting ~/android-studio and reinstalling it from freshly downloaded archive did not help either. Any modified file un-blues as soon as I press ctrl+s.